# How to have two different headers for two different modes with header2?

Tags: file-header

How to have two different headers for two different modes with [`header2`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el)?

For instance, to have a header like :

```
% ----------
% File-name : 
% ----------
```

when I create a `.el` file and a header like :

```
# ----------
# Location :
# ----------
```

when I create a `.R` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Commentary of file [`header2.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el):

```
;;     Mode-specific headers:
;;     ---------------------
;;      Not all headers need look alike.  Suppose that you have a unix script mode
;;      and want it to have a shell specifier line that all other headers do not
;;      have.  To do this, Place the following line in a hook called when the
;;      mode is invoked or in the code that establishes the mode:
;;
;;         (add-hook 'make-header-hook 'header-shell nil t)
;;
;;      The header building blocks are sensitive to the different comment
;;      characters in different modes.
```

In addition, if you need to you can make any of the user options that define parts of the header buffer-local, i.e., specific to a given mode.  And if you really need to, you can do likewise for `make-header-hook`.

Comment: I already read this part of `header2.el`'s header, but I don't understand how to do so.

Comment: I finally get it ! I defined two functions for locally setting `make-header-hook` and then added these functions to mode hooks. Thank you for your answer.